# Most recent files on folders and sub folders, as a whole not spread by folders

Tags: dos, command-prompt

I know some of DOS, I can do simple things but havent been able to find or create something for a search of recent files on a folder with sub-folders.

```
dir *.mp3 /b /o:d /s /t:c > Listing.txt
```

This works fine, with one issue, it lists the recent folder on from each folder, not a list as a whole. I want a list of recent files on everything, kinda like what windows does if you do a search by date.

```
music  \Josh
       \Rafael
```

The script I have will do what I need but it will give me the newest file on each folder one after the another, not as a whole, so lets say like this:

```
Music\file 1.mp3
Music\file 2.mp3
Music\Josh\file24.mp3
Music\Josh\file50.mp3
Music\Rafael\test1.mp3
Music\Rafael\test56.mp3
```

what I would like is to be the recent files regardless off folders, kinda like this

```
file 1.mp3
file24.mp3
test1.mp3
file 2.mp3
file50.mp3
test56.mp3
```

Rafael

Comment: Try this `For /r %I in (*.mp3) do @echo %~nxI`

Comment: Now is there a way to add dates next to the file names? :D

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.computerhope.com/forhlp.htm) for different options. I think `~nxtI` should return date, i posted my comment as answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the files sorted by date and time, you can use a batch file like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,*" %%f in ('dir /s') do call :eachfile %%f %%g %%h "%%i" "%%j"
exit /b

:eachfile
set dt=%1
set tm=%2
if "%dt%"=="Directory" exit /b
if "%dt%"=="Volume" exit /b
if "%tm%"=="File(s)" exit /b
if "%tm%"=="Dir(s)" exit /b
if "%dt%"=="Total" exit /b
if "%~4"=="<DIR>" exit /b
echo %dt:~6,4%/%dt:~0,5% %3 %tm% %~5
exit /b
```

Save that to e.g. `dirflat.bat`, then you can run

```
dirflat | sort
```

to get the list of files in order.  If you aren't in the U.S., you might need to tweak the next-to-last line of the batch file to chop and splice your directory listings correctly.  For me, that turns:

```
06/14/2011 10:40 AM "209,920" "sed.exe"
```

into

```
2011/06/14 AM 10:40 sed.exe
```

which can be easily sorted.  You could then send the output through another stage to strip the times off the beginning of the string.

Comment: David O'Riva thanks so much you took to another level and it work perfectly. thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
For /r %I in (*.mp3) do @echo %~nxI
```

To include dates in result do this

```
For /r %I in (*.mp3) do @echo %~nxtI
```

For different modifiers please refer [this url](http://www.computerhope.com/forhlp.htm)